# Naming and calling elements in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, naming

I'm new on this site, and I don't even know if I'm posting on the right section but here we go.

I'm writing a simple HTML file with a CSS attached, in the HTML, I have a piece of code that is like this:

```
<ul id="thing_list">

    <li>
        <div>
            <header>
                <h2>Name of the thing</h2>
                <p>Some thing here</p>
            </header>
            <nav>
                <ul id="actions">
                    <li>Edit</li>
                    <li>Move</li>
                    <li>Delete</li>
                </ul>
            <nav>
        </div>
    </li>
```

And the CSS for this is like:

```
#thing_list li > div > nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#actions li {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

So, the question is, which way is better for me to name things? Is is better to define an ID/Class for everything or to define a few and use #thing_list li > div > nav li?

I'm not so sure if you guys can understand, english is not my main language, so please bear with me on that.

Comment: There are lot of resources online to help you with this, for example http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/ One key thing to remember is that ID must be unique

Comment: it depends what you are planning to do with your site. Otherwise whatever is more comfortable for you.

Comment: `id` 's must be unique, hence the name id. A `class` attribute can be attached to multiple elements. Classes are a way of grouping similar elements, e.g a `<li class='nav-list' id='home'>Home</li> <li class='nav-list' id='about'>About Me</li>`

Comment: First you really need to understand how selector works. what  if you use `>` in your CSS. do you understand it.

Comment: My second suggestion is don't use so long group `#thing_list li > div > nav li ` because it will take more time to Browser read this full syntax.

Comment: My best advice is to try to capture the semantics of the content, such that similar content will naturally match the same selector. But that's a real skill all in itself, one that will take experience to learn. In the meantime, study the [CSS Level 3 Selector spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) carefully, so you understand the full richness of the tools available to you.

Answer (score 2):

The big difference between CSS classes and CSS IDs is that a CSS class name can be used several times, while the CSS IDs are only used once. CSS IDs are used to apply CSS styles to the element and only element identified by the CSS ID. CSS classes should be used for items that you know you are going to use a lot. For example, using a common CSS class name, you can give the same styling to all tables on your webpage. The use of `#thing_list li > div > nav li` is not recommended as it takes extra time to process. Hope it useful!

Comment: theres no such thing as css classes or ids. they are html classes and ids

Comment: I know. But it's more easy to explain it this way. I've should used terms like CSS selectors instead!

Answer (score 0):

First, use correct HTML (you better us `dl/dt/dd` for your example).

See css is "Cascading", so need to override styles in growing specificy. Depending of your choice of specificy.

**Note:** ID's shall be unique in a document because of the url-anchor.

If you say: Every input field must be blue but saluation must be red, you write this:

```
 <label>Name: <input></label>
 <label>Saluation: <input class="sal" ></label>

 <style>
 input{
     background-color:blue;
 }
 input.sal{ 
     background-color:red;
 }
 </style>
```

In this example you have the freedom to be more specific to the second input. Maybe you need the freedom in the future.

So **exceptions** shall always be more specific than **generals**.

Comment: You will see, techniques like a `normalizer.css` or a `reset.css` are of **very** general specifity.